# Database connections not being closed on oracle server

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, ado.net, connection-pooling

I am experiencing a problem where by when connecting to an Oracle11g database using NHibernate, old connections in the pool are not being closed.

I am fairly sure that all the NHibernate sessions are disposed properly, however the connections still remain in an `INACTIVE` status. I know this will be because of connection pooling, however surley they should be removed after a certain amount of time? If not how can I configure this to happen.

I have tried adding the following settings into my connection string:

```
Max Pool Size=10;
Connection Lifetime=120;
Incr Pool Size=1;
Decr Pool Size=10;`
```

This seems to stop as many connections being created, I guess because this increase size is an increment of 1, however once the connections have been put back into the pool they are never closed.

I have looked at the v$session table and some of the `LASST_CALL_ET` values were as much as 786465s or 9 days!!

I am fairly sure all the sessions are being disposed, here is an example of the code:

```
public class DoSomethingToDb(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
  using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
  {
      session.Transaction.Begin();
      //Do Stuff
      session.Transaction.Commit();
  }
}
```

How can I setup my program/NHibernate/Ado.Net/Oracle to close connections that are no longer in use.

The server we were testing on crashed yesterday as there were over 800 `INACTVIE` connections and no more could be issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was being caused by the use of transactions. Removing the transactions from the above code produced the following:

```
public class DoSomethingToDb(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
  using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
  {

      //Do Stuff
      session.Flush();
  }
}
```

Which seems to cause no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having problems is because your **Decr Pool Size** value is too large.  It will not be able to close any connections unless all of them are available to close since your **Decr Pool Size** is the same as your **Max Pool Size**.

When i have set this value to 1, it takes for ever to release unused connections.  I am currently setting mine to 5 and it still takes just as long between each decrements, but it will release more at once.

```
Pooling=true; 
Min Pool Size=0;
Max Pool Size=10;
Incr Pool Size=1;
Decr Pool Size=3;
```

Also, with **Connection Lifetime** being set to 120, it will not keep any sessions open for more than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It would surprise me if you could do this in hibernate since I think the connections are leaked connections. For some reason they got out of control and won't ever be reused.

What you can do is configure an session idle timeout in resource manager in the Oracle database. See [Managing Resources with Oracle Database Resource Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17636/dbrm.htm#ADMIN027)

Make sure that a resource consumer group is defined for your pooled sessions and that the idle timeout is big enough to not unexpectedly interrupt a working healthy session.

Oracle Database Resource Manager is a very flexible and powerful tool that can help your system in many ways.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. Is there a know bug in nhibernate which would cause the connections to be leaked? Or could it be an error in my application?

Comment: I don't know hibernate but as far as I know, an app should pick a connection from the pool and return it too, also under exception conditions. So, yes, an app can be in error, maybe hibernate handles that .... I don't know.

Comment: Okay, it seems an odd problem as we cant recreate it. If we set the Max Pool Size to 10 and then try to open 11 connections, on opening the 11th we get an exception as expected. At the moment we seemed to have solved the issue by disabling connection pooling, using `Pooling=false`

Comment: Hard to call that a solution .... This breaks scalability since connect/disconnect actions in the database are serialized. That is the reason for wanting a connection pool in the first place.

Comment: True, it also didn't solve the problem. Everything runs fine for 12 hours or so. And then connections are left inactive.

Comment: are your connections returned to the pool after an exception took place? In weblogic we can set session idle time. This makes that wls forces/harvests connections back into the pool after a specified idle time.

Comment: I'm not sure, is there any way I can check? I know that I dispose the session on an exception (because of the using statement). But I guess they are not returned to the pool somewhere. As when we had over 800 connections we had specified the `Max Pool Size` to be 10

Comment: Does the last_call_et in the v$session table not show the when the session last did something, i.e. Idle time

Comment: last_call_et gives last time server was called, could also be a very long running call ... Check the connection pool advanced settings for the timout upon which the harvesting takes place.

Comment: If the state is INACTIVE though, would last_call_et not be correct. How does one check the connection pool? In oracle (commands / sqldeveloper), sorry I am not a DBA.

Comment: last_call_et is correct, no worries about that. The connection pool is in the middleware. On what middleware is your app deployed?

Comment: We are using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver and NHibernate, if that's what you mean? Other than that and our software, nothing else is installed.

Comment: for me it ends here. Try resource manager. It is very powerful. Your app has a problem but resource manager can help to reduce the impact.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I will have to track down why disposed sessions aren't being closed in my applicaiton